# how to override wagtail admin login page

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to build my own custom login page for wagtail admin login page. Everything is working fine I removed all the content by extending

> {% extends "wagtailadmin/login.html" %}

Login is working but the default sign in button is still showing in my custom login page. How to remove it.
Here my own custom login page code is

```html
{% extends "wagtailadmin/login.html" %}
{% load staticfiles i18n  %}
    {% block css  %}
      #Loaded my css files here
    {% endblock %}
{% block branding_login %}{% endblock %} # to Remove branding login(login to wagtail site)

{% block fields  %}

  #Login form here 
  
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace the submit button, define a `submit_buttons` block on your template.

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html#submit-buttons

Comment: is there any block to override messages of admin login Page ( example message: Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.)

Comment: Don't post follow up questions as comment. Just ask a new question. All strings are translatable. Just add your own translation. Wagtail is a Django app so Django  docs apply. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS (last paragraph) and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/